# How do I stop asking the same questions on dialogflow?

Tags: dialogflow-es

I'm new to dialogflow. In my default Hello Intent, I have something like this:

Good day! My name is xyz and I'm here to help you. May I know your name please?

This response is for when users say something like "hi"

After that, I will pass the context to another Intent to wait for the name input

[image]

I would like to avoid asking these information if I already have the user's contact information. Is there away to check for the context and trigger a different response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just need to check if the context contains a property called "name" or similar, simply add a parameter in the second intent, set its value to `#awaiting_contact.name` and enable the mandatory option. That will let you define prompts if the property has no value, so you can re-ask the user.

However, I'm not sure what the Welcome Intent context has. You are just giving a welcome message. Then, when the user inputs his name, this will trigger a different intent.

Comment: You are exactly right, right now I only ask the name in the welcome response and then the name intent should pickup if the name is returned. (I will update the question with the new screenshot). I will try what you suggest and see what happens.